# Multiple JavaScript files in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I ask myself if it is possible to split up a single dart.js into multiple files. I just seek a possibility to convert several independent used JavaScript components in something that is as reusable but yet independently used Dart equivalents.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at [DeferredLibrary](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/DeferredLibrary.html) and the issue [Enable dart2js to split output into N files to reduce initial download size](http://dartbug.com/3940) (**WARNING** : the issue is not yet fixed).

Comment: I don't think the N bit is implemented yet - can only split into 2 files at the moment. Perhaps make that more clear in your answer.

Comment: I want to wait until the better integration with JavaScript hits the road. I sometimes wonder why there is no easy way to split the code in multiple files that compile to JavaScript but actually work like Jars. Maybe its the threading model... .