# How to achieve single page app with multiple views in Dart?

Tags: gwt, dart, mvp, single-page-application

I am migrating from GWT to Dart and would like to take the MVP pattern that [I learned from building GWT apps](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) and use them in Dart-land. I'm playing around with my first Dart app and would like it to be a "single-page" app, meaning that the view can change at the drop of a hat without forcing the user to suffer a page load. GWT solves this (in part) with it's Activities & Places API, and I'm wondering if Dart has anything similar.

1. What does Dart offer developers in the way of creating single-page apps, and if it doesn't, how do other Dart developers achieve single-page apps?
2. GWT uses [codesplitting and fragmentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) to minimize the amount of time the application takes to load. Does Dart offer anything like this, or can it be "hacked" to emulate these concepts?

Answer (score 2):

1) Depending on frameworks there are different ways to do that. For instance [angular.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart) can handle [views and routing](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki/Creating-views#using-routing-to-create-views). An other solution is the [route package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route).

2) See [Mulitple JavaScript files in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611705/mulitple-javascript-files-in-dart/20611877#20611877)

Answer (score 0):

1) Using Polymer elements as views works fine too.